# Python Module error for requests on centos7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-requests, centos

I am having trouble trying to install Python requests module on centos. I tried installing Python requests using yum and pip (I think I am on the old version pip, I am having trouble installing pip3 as well). I was only able to install requests for python2.7 which is already past end of life.

I tried installing pip3 using yum:

```
sudo yum -y install python36-pip.noarch
```

Here are options I have tried

```
pip install requests 
yum install -y python36u python36u-libs python36u-devel python36u-pip
```

Its just been an overall mess trying to install the updated requests module on centos for me.

Comment: The question is... what do you need a newer requests module for? For custom script coding, in RHEL based system specifically, you absolutely want to use a `virtualenv` if you want to code stuff against the latest Python modules. And you should never use `pip` outside `virtualenv`s anyway because you risk of breaking the entire system.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was installing requests library for another python and my python3 was `ln -s` to `/bin/python3` I just referenced the correct python to the library that the requests library was installed on.